# Best method to create links to List Item's Workflow using results of SPServices - GetListItems

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I am using SPServices - GetListItems ajax to retrieve data from SharePoint 2010 for a Kendo Grid. I then bind the Title to a URL template. This works okay (except one the grid's linkouts generates a Cross-site scripting error that clicks through to the item. This is odd, because the page and the link are in the same site).

I would prefer to link to the underlying Workflow Instance, but cannot find the unique ID required in any of the results or underlying XML data (as viewed through Stramit Caml Viewer) returned by GetListItems.

This feels clunky and hard-coded, and likely to break if someone changes a particular environments Lists.

In a perfect world, I would be able to retrieve the entire link from the ListItem as it shows in SharePoint and emit that in my custom page.

Is there any way to do this?

**Edit**
The List Items I am retrieving are from a Library with columns that display links that take you to an item's associated Workflow. I want to link directly to this workflow from the item displayed in my grid, as if I were looking at the Document Library itself in SharePoint. Code:

```
var carformData = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "CAR Form",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='WorkflowInstanceID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='CAR_x0020_ID' /><FieldRef Name='Phase1Fi' /><FieldRef Name='Phase2Ex' /><FieldRef Name='APPceo' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                carformData.push({
                    Title: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
                    Modified: $(this).attr("ows_Modified"),
                    CARID: $(this).attr("ows_CAR_x0020_ID") != undefined ? $(this).attr("ows_CAR_x0020_ID") : "",
                    Phase1: $(this).attr("ows_Phase1Fi") != undefined ? workflowStatusCodes[$(this).attr("ows_Phase1Fi")] : "",
                    Phase2: $(this).attr("ows_Phase2Ex") != undefined ? workflowStatusCodes[$(this).attr("ows_Phase2Ex")] : "",
                    Phase3: $(this).attr("ows_APPceo")!= undefined ? workflowStatusCodes[$(this).attr("ows_APPceo")] : "",
                    WorkflowID: $(this).attr("ows_WorkflowInstanceID") //Note: This never has a value, even though these list items are associated with a Workflow, and display a link to them when viewing the Library
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $("#gridCar").kendoGrid({
        sortable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "Title", title: "Name", template: "<a href='/CIS/CAR%20Form/${ Title }'>${ Title }</a>" },
            { field: "Modified", title: "Modified", format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}",  width: 80, headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: center" } },
            { field: "CARID", title: "CAR ID", width: 80, headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: center" } },
            { field: "Phase1", title: "Phase 1 - Finance & Accounting", width: 192 },
            { field: "Phase2", title: "Phase 2 - Executive Approval", width: 182 },
            { field: "Phase3", title: "Phase 3 - CEO Approval", width: 151 }
        ],
        dataSource: {
            data: carformData,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Title: { type: "string" },
                        Modified: { type: "date" },
                        CARID: { type: "string" },
                        Phase1: { type: "string" },
                        Phase2: { type: "string" },
                        Phase3: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand what you're trying to do here... Do you need JavaScript or a simple Workflow can work for you? Otherwise you may also want to try my JavaScript API for Sharepoint http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ -- I don't know if that could help you in any way...

Comment: Hi AymKdn, please see the edits above

Comment: Ok I think I now understand... However I never tried something like that, and right now I have no clue... If you find the solution, please share it here !